# Why can't create an array of Protocol conformance objects in Swift?

Tags: swift

I have created the following protocol and enum conforming to the protocol as shown below:

```
protocol HamburgerOption {

    static var all :[HamburgerOption] { get }
    var title :String { get }
}

enum Meat :HamburgerOption {

    private static var allCases :[Meat] = [.chicken, .beef]

    case chicken
    case beef

    static var all :[HamburgerOption] {
        return Meat.allCases
    }

    var title :String {
        switch self {
            case .chicken:
                return "Chicken"
            case .beef:
                return "Beef"
        }
    }
}
```

When I create the following struct it gives me error:

```
// Value of type 'Meat.Type' does not conform to expected element type //'HamburgerOption'

    struct HamburgerOptions  {

        var all :[HamburgerOption] {
            return [Meat, Sauces]
        }
    }
```

Comment: `all` is an array of `HamburgerOption`, so you’d need something like `var all: [HamburgerOption] { return [Meat.beef, Sauces.ketchup] }`. You need array of `HamburgerOption` values, not of `HamburgerOption` types. Or if you wanted `all` to be all `Meat` values and all `Sauces` values, then `var all :[HamburgerOption] { return Meat.all + Sauces.all }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your property is defined to return an array of instances that conform to `HamburgerOption`. However, by returning `[Meat, Sauces]`, you are returning an array of *types* rather than *instances*. What you need to do is to return an array of *instances*. You can do this simply by adding the results of the `all` methods for your types:

```
return Meat.all + Sauces.all
```

(For any Sheldon Cooper wannabes out there, yes, if he actually needed to make an array of types, he'd need to postpend each one with `.self`)